# Amplify - Xcode Previews

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify, swiftui-previews

I'm trying to get previews in Xcode 15 however it always fails to load, showing the following issue:

I'm getting the following error in my AppDelegate:

```
could not find module 'Amplify' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator,
```

I see plenty of issues online (not with Amplify) for an error the other way around i.e.

```
could not find module 'x' for target 'arm64'; found: 'x86_64'
```

but not my issue.

Has anyone ran into this issue before?

Comment: It looks like Amplify doesn’t support simulator. You would have to mock it somehow if you don’t have a testing device

Comment: I do have a testing device, but of course constructing UI is much easier in the previews than "guessing" and building on a testing device.

Comment: @loremipsum Seems like Amplify should support it. There's multiple closed issues on their github page in regards to previews. No one seems to have had this particular issue though.

Comment: If you mean by [Amplify-Swift](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift), it is working for me on the preview. Please share a minimum reproducible project here or on git and link here

Comment: Can you give details on what machine, and simulator are you trying to run on?

Answer (score 0):

open XCode > -Your Main Target- > Build Active Architecture Only and set 'NO' to build on the all architectures.

Options:

YES - If set to yes, then Xcode will detect the device that is connected, and determine the architecture, and build on just that architecture alone.

NO - If set to no, then it will build on all the architectures.

Comment: Setting to NO causes the error: 
``Could not find module 'Amplify' for target 'x86_64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-ios-simulator``

Comment: Tell me how I can reproduce all this in my machine. Then after I will try